# Can you cast a QReal digit to a float?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QPointF, where it has .x() and .y() methods, which are qreal objects.  Can these be cast to floats?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can.  On ARM platforms, they already are floats.  Otherwise, it's a double.  A static cast or a C-style cast will do it.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qreal-typedef

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qreal-typedef) says it's usually a double, but sometimes a float.  So if you have to cast, it's preferable to cast to double, which should be safe and avoids narrowing.  You can cast to float if necessary though.